# Глагол в конце предложения

Tags: стилистика

Когда я строю предложения, у меня часто глагол или наречие попадают на последнее место. В принципе, так говорят, но мне это все равно немного режет слух. Ну, например:
*Я делаю эту ошибку **постоянно**.

У меня тоже собака **есть**.*

Вроде, ничего такого, но это получается довольно часто. Нужно ли стараться этого избегать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело не в глаголе или наречии. На "последнее место" Вы ставите то, что является новым, важным, актуальным в Вашем предложении.

В  предложении  отчетливо выделяются две части: исходный пункт высказывания, который часто бывает известен или может угадываться по ситуации (тема), и вторая часть, которая содержит именно то, что представляет собой главную коммуникативную цель высказывания (рема) Членение предложения-высказывания на тему и рему называется  актуальным  членением. Главным средством передачи разного актуального содержания является порядок слов.

ТАк что никаких ошибок Вы не делаете. А с помощью порядка слов выделяете главное, новое в Вашем высказывании.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке очень важна структура и интонация предложения, но эта тема изучается у нас мало и мало понимается (отсюда, мне кажется, следуют представления о влиянии других языков на нашу речь).

Выраженная с помощью окончаний синтаксическая связь слов позволяет применять их свободный порядок, который (как здесь уже говорилось) дополнительно выражает смысловые отношения "тема - рема" (актуальное членение). Но и внутри каждой части (темы и ремы)порядок слов может меняться, обеспечивая логическое выделение нужного слова.

Например, сообщение "У меня тоже (пауза) есть собака" (1) можно перестроить следующим образом: У меня тоже (пауза) собака есть(2). Актуальное членение здесь одинаково, а логическое выделение слов различно.

Предложение 1 воспринимается как нейтральное сообщение -  тоническое ударение падает на слово "собака", стоящее в конце предложение (это обычная норма).

Предложение  2 имеет повышенную экспрессию, при которой слово "собака" логически подчеркнуто. Это достигается инверсией подлежащего и сказуемого: тоническое ударение перемещается на второе от конца слово (отклонение от нормы) и тем самым выделяет слово "собака".

Comment: София, хотелось бы еще разбор предложений: "собака у меня тоже есть", "у меня собака тоже есть".

Answer (score 0):

Я не специалист по русскому языку, но слышал такое мнение, что глагол в конце предложения 1) свойственен устной речи, 2) [заимствован из немецкого языка](http://usenet.su/showthread.php/510361-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) (активно использовался в XVIII веке, а в XIX веке под влиянием французского языка стал использоваться меньше), 3) ошибочен (Познер В.В. сказал в какой-то передаче). Лично мне это режет слух, звучит как какое-то нарочитое просторечие. По крайней мере, в письме я стараюсь этого избегать.